# Anaconda installation completely busted

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

I have no Idea what is going wrong, but whenever I install anaconda, then run the prompt, navigator, or shell, right out of the box before I even do anything I get the same error no matter what I do.

Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\MY_IRL_NAME\anaconda3\python.exe "C:\Users\MY_IRL_NAME\anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py" shell.cmd.exe activate "C:\Users\MY_IRL_NAME\anaconda3" '

I have tried everything other than messing around with path variables manually, I also cant use the prompt at all to try to update it because any conda command is unreconized by anaconda. I've wasted 3 hours trying to figure this out and I just can't, any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried,

- uninstalling all instalations of python, and setting anaconda to default.
- redownloading anaconda.
- adding anaconda instalation to path.
- restarting laptop
- and pretty much all of the simple things that I can think of

Comment: Where did you get the Anaconda installer, exactly?  What kind of computer are you running it on, meaning what kind of processor is it?  And which operating system?

Comment: A Lenovo think pad, intel i5 12th gen processor for laptop. T500 Gpu, 16gb ram, 256gb storage, Windows 11.

I got the installer from the anaconda website Under the windows download section.

https://www.anaconda.com/download

Comment: ok so I got it working, but idrk why. I had to install it with admin privileges under all users (even though there's only one). but after I did that, everything works.